# Cómo utilizar subcarpetas dentro de Modules Controllers usando nWidart

Tags: laravel, controller, modular

Buen día a todos.

Estoy usando módulos dentro del proyecto, construidos mediante el desarrollo de **nWidart**.

Aunque en su documentación menciona la posibilidad de manejar carpetas dentro de la carpeta de *Controllers*, no detalla como hacerlo y no he podido hacerlo andar. Supongo que es algo muy sencillo, pero no he dado en lo correcto.

Les comento que es lo que tengo hecho, a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Esta es la estructura deseada:

```
miProyecto
  Modules
    Solicitud
      Http
        Controllers
          back
            AdminController.php
          front
            VisitController.php
```

Este es mi *Modules/Solicita/Routes/web.php*

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'solicita', 'uses' => 'SolicitaController@index']);
});
```

Y este es *Modules/Http/Controllers/Admin/SolicitaController.php*

```
namespace Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class SolicitaController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        dd('ESTAS EN ADMIN SOLICITA');
        return view('solicita::index');
    }
}
```

Luego `composer dump-autoload`, voy a la ruta: `localhost/miproyecto/public/admin` y me da este error:

> ```
> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target class [Modules\Solicita\Http\Controllers\Admin\SolicitaController] does >not exist.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta era muy sensilla.

Crear las subcarpetas, por ejemplo `\Controllers\Front`, dentro se coloca el *controller*. Hay que setear el *namespace* del controller como *namespace* `Modules\ModuloX\Http\Controllers\Front` y en la ruta se coloca `Route::get('cliente/listar', 'Front\ClienteController@listar')`

La view y lo demás queda igual.